# How to select these elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to handler all elements with the attribute `rel` inside of an `a` elements that start with string `lightbox`.

How can I do it with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector.

```
$('a [rel^="lightbox"]')
```

**EDIT:** having re-read your question, it sounds like this may be what you want:

```
$('a[id^="lightbox"] [rel]')
```

This selects all elements that have the attribute `rel` and are within an `a` tag that has an ID starting with `lightbox`.

Comment: @markzzz: Ah, you accepted whilst I was editing, guess I was right first time! To be fair though I think @Box9's answer was first.

Answer (score 5):

With the [attribute-starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('a [rel^="lightbox"]')
```

Comment: You need to remove the space between `a` and `[´.

Comment: @RoToRa - nope, OP wants "elements ... **inside** ... of a elements". Though, it is a little ambiguously worded so I may have interpreted wrong :)

Answer (score 4):

you need [startswith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```
 $('a[rel^="lightbox"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be different... if it is a prefix (i.e. "lightbox-") you can use the `|=` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/).

```
$('a[rel|=lightbox]')
```